# nodejs express knex master detail record update

Tags: node.js, express, master-detail, knex.js, yield-return

I have master(Workbook) & Child(WorkBookDataset). I am trying to update master and at the same time (insert or update or delete) child records. Everything works fine except it is not returning the updated child records. I know I am doing something wrong while specifying the 'then', and as it is always asyc operation, the result is already returned before child updates complete.

```js
var Promise = require('bluebird');
    
    return knex.transaction(function(trx) {
        return knex('workbook').where('workbookid',workbook.workbookid).andWhere('userid', workbook.userid)            
        .update(workbook)
        .then(function(updatedrecords) {
            return Promise.map(datasets, function(dataset) {
                if(dataset.workbookdatasetid && dataset.workbookdatasetid == -1){                        
                    //remove
                    return knex('workbookdataset').where('workbookid',workbook.workbookid).andWhere('datasetid', dataset.datasetid)
                    .delete();
                } else {
                dataset.workbookid = workbook.workbookid;
                
                knex('workbookdataset').where('workbookid',workbook.workbookid).andWhere('datasetid', dataset.datasetid)
                .then(function(alreadyds) {                        
                    if(alreadyds.length == 1){
                        //update                            
                        return knex('workbookdataset').where('workbookid',workbook.workbookid).andWhere('datasetid', dataset.datasetid)
                        .update(dataset)
                    }else{
                        //insert
                        if(dataset.workbookdatasetid){
                            delete dataset.workbookdatasetid;
                        }                            
                        return knex('workbookdataset')
                        .insert(dataset)
                    }
                    })   
                }
                });
        })
    })
    .then(function(updatedrecords) {
        return getWorkBook(workbook.userid, workbook.workbookid); //this returns updated workbook information, but not updated workbookdataset information
    });
```

I tried putting then() to Promise, but still same. Any help/pointer would be a great help! Thanks in advance!

Comment: Which database are you using?

Answer (score 1):

You need a `return` on the line where you have `knex('workbookdataset').where('workbookid'`

Comment: wow! it worked. How silly it was. Thanks. (I am using new id, they did not let me mark as answer)

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at a `.returning` method from knex [documentation](http://knexjs.org/#Builder-returning). It allows you to return inserted/updated/deleted records from a database.

Also, I'd recommend you to check your promise chain to be sure you are returning correct values in correct places.

P.S. This is not related to question but if you are using transactions add to your queries `.transacting(trx)` to actually run them in one transaction instead of separately.

```
knex('workbook')
  .where('workbookid',workbook.workbookid)
  .andWhere('userid', workbook.userid)            
  .update(workbook)
  .returning('*')
  .transacting(trx)
  .then(data => {
     console.log(data) // => [{id: 1, workbookid: 1, userid: 981,...}, ...]
  })
```

Comment: Yeah, got it. Thanks.